# Can't install .app on simulator via command line

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, appium-ios, simctl

I'm using appium for ios test automation. Lately, I get an error when installing an .app on a simulator. I could reproduce that locally.

**Command line execution**, that fails:

```
xcrun simctl install DEVICE_ID /full/path/to/app
```

**Error message**:

> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
>   Failed to install the requested application
>   An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
>   Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.

**However!**

When I drag the .app on the Simulator, it works just fine.
The deviceId is correct. I can easily boot and shutdown the simulator via `xcrun simctl`.
This is on our CI mac slave. Running locally on my mac (with same versions) works just fine.

**Environment**:

`OS version`: 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.5
BuildVersion:   17F77

`Xcode version`: 9.4

`Command line tools version`: 9.4

`xcrun version`: 
xcrun version 43

`simctl version`: 
@(#)PROGRAM:simctl  PROJECT:CoreSimulator-518.22

`Simulator under test`:
iPhone SE (11.4)

I would be very about any hints.

Comment: It sounds like the path you are passing is incorrect...

Comment: Yes, it does sound like that, but it is correct. I would like to know, what else can cause this error. Or is there a problem with the built app.

Comment: Does your path have spaces in it? Drag and drop uses the exact same API to install the app so if it works in one it will work in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. Good to know, that drag and drop uses the same API. 
I found out, what was the issue. The path was really incorrect. However, cd'ing into the path worked, that's why I thought, the path can't be the issue.

The actual path was "/Users/Jenkins/..." but I used "/Users/jenkins..." because this was returned by the jenkins' pwd function. Seems like our jenkins slave was misconfigured.

So, somehow cd could handle the incorrect casing, while xcrun simctl couldn't.

Comment: Yes, simulators run with a special case-sensitive VFS policy (because that's how actual devices work), so everything inside the Simulator is case-sensitive even when your mac is on a case in-sensitive volume.

Comment: I had the same problem with react native for some reason. Simply deleting the .app folder caused it to work again. Because it had created an `AppName.app` instead of `Appname.app` folder.